# How to hook into Workspace-startup process in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, workspace

When developing an Eclipse plug-in, is there a way to hook into the workspace (not workbench) startup- or initialization process? I'd like my plug-in to be notified when all the projects belonging to the workspace are known. The project-lifecycle and resource listeners only provide callbacks for modification, creation or deletion of projects. What I need is a kind of an inverse [WorkspaceSaveParticipant](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_saving.htm)-mechanism.

Note that this is within the context of IDE-plugins, not RCP-applications, so some of the solutions that might apply to an RCP-application are out of scope for me (I don't know whether plain RCP-apps have projects at all).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [org.eclipse.ui.startup](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html) extension point.

Comment: Is this still - say in 3.6 - the recommended way? Also, I'd need a hook that runs as late as possible after UI and everything is up, as a low priority job (to avoid delaying more important/core initialisation). Thanks.